# Remove until specific char in string (Python)

Tags: python

I want to remove something from the start and end of a string before writing to the `.txt`

I'm reading an incoming string from a serial port. I want to write the string to a `.txt` file, which I can do. I've tried using the `rstrip()` (also tried `strip()`) function to remove the 'OK' in the end, but with no luck.

Ideally, I want the program to be dynamic so I can use it for other files. This gives a problem, because the unwanted text in the start and end of the string might vary, so I can't look for specific chars/words to remove.

While this is said, all unwanted text in the start of the string will start with a `'+'` like in the example below (It might be possible to check if the first line starts with a '+' and remove it if it does. This would be ideal).

```
def write2file():
    print "Listing local files ready for copying:"
    listFiles()
    print 'Enter name of file to copy:'
    name = raw_input()
    pastedFile = [] 
    tempStr = readAll('AT+URDFILE="' + name + '"') #Calls another function who reads the file locally and return it in a string
    tempStr = tempStr.rstrip('OK') #This is where I try to remove the 'OK' I know is going to be in the end of the string
    pastedFile[:0] = tempStr #Putting the string into a list. Workaround for writing 128 bytes at a time. I know it's not pretty, but it works :-)
    print 'Enter path to file directory'
    path =  raw_input()
    myFile = open(join(path, name),"w")
    while len(pastedFile):
        tempcheck  = pastedFile[0:128]
        for val in tempcheck:
            myFile.write(val)
        del pastedFile[0:128]
    myFile.close()
```

I expect the `.txt` to include all the text from the local file, but remove the `OK` in the end. When program is run it returns:

> +URDFILE: "develop111.txt",606,"** ((content of local file)) OK

The 'OK' I wanted to be removed is still in there.

The text `"+URDFILE: "develop111.txt",606,"` is also unwanted in the final .txt file.

**So summarizes the problem:**

How can I remove the unwanted text in the start and end of a string, before writing it to a .txt file

Comment: Are you trying to get just 'develop111.txt' from the string?

Comment: Your question is not clear. You're saying ``all unwanted text will start with a '+'`` but in your example you only want to ``remove the OK in the end``. You should edit your question and add more examples of input vs actual output vs expected output.

Comment: you want `+` to be removed from the begining, and `OK` to be removed from the last right

Comment: I just made an edit to show where my wanted content is. It's in between " +URDFILE: "develop111.txt",606,"" and "OK"

Comment: @Jeril I want to remove the text on both sides of ((content of local file)).

Comment: @MikeScotty Thanks, I just did. I see how the question was confusing

Comment: Hi. You might try looking into the `split` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your `URDFILE` is always has the same return pattern `+URDFILE: "filname",filesize,"filedata"\nOK` as it is AT command. So, it should be enough to `''.join(tempStr.split(',')[3:])[:-3]`

Working example:

```
>>> s = '+URDFILE: "filname",filesize,"filedata, more data"\nOK' 
>>> ','.join(s.split(',')[2:])[:-3]
'"filedata, more data"'
```

or to remove with quotes:

```
>>>','.join(s.split(',')[2:])[1:-4]
'filedata, more data'
```

Comment: Thanks, this was just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```py
tempStr = '+URDFILE: "develop111.txt",606,"** ((content of local file)) OK'
tempStr = tempStr.strip()
if tempStr.startswith('+'):
    tempStr = tempStr[1:]
if tempStr.endswith('OK'):
    tempStr = tempStr[:-2]
print(tempStr)
```

Output:

```
URDFILE: "develop111.txt",606,"** ((content of local file))
```

If you want to select the required text then you can use `regex` for that. Can you try the following:

```
import re
tempStr = 'URDFILE: "develop111.txt",606,"** 01((content of local file)) OK'
tempStr = tempStr.strip()
if tempStr.startswith('+'):
    tempStr = tempStr[1:]
if tempStr.endswith('OK'):
    tempStr = tempStr[:-2]

# print(tempStr)
new_str = ''.join(re.findall(r'01(.+)', tempStr))
new_str = new_str.strip()
print(new_str)
```

Output:

```
((content of local file))
```

Comment: This is what I hoped I could do to remove the OK at the end. Thanks a bunch! 
If I want to remove `+URDFILE: "develop111.txt",606,"**` so i only get ((content of local file)), how would I go about that? I assume that ((content of local file)) always start with "01" if that might help

Comment: I got some suspect outputs, but Im sure it's doable your way. I went with another answer, but thanks for taking the time!